# How to download a file from Kaggle and work on it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, wget

I want to download a dataset from Kaggle in python then work on it. When I click the download button say on this page https://www.kaggle.com/quora/question-pairs-dataset

[image]

my browser is loading a zip file. However if I do in python

```
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get("https://www.kaggle.com/quora/question-pairs-dataset/download")
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall(os.getcwd())
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u\Documents\Maths\Code\Variational Auto Encoders\VAE_text_generation.py", line 33, in <module>
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Any solution for getting the file from the url - unzip if needed - and get the name of the downloaded file so as to be able to work on it ?

EDIT Also tested the following which does not produce an error but files are not the .csv and .txt I expect, probably because they have not been unzipped or could not be uploaded correctly for rights were missing.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def report(num, size, total):
    print(num*size, '/', total)

# get kaggle data 
urlretrieve("https://www.kaggle.com/quora/question-pairs-dataset/download","train.csv",reporthook=report)
TRAIN_DATA_FILE = os.getcwd() + 'train.csv' 

## get glove 

urlretrieve("https://www.kaggle.com/watts2/glove6b50dtxt/download",
    "glove.txt",reporthook=report)
GLOVE_EMBEDDING = os.getcwd() + 'glove.txt'
```

Comment: Inspect what `r.content` contains. I believe you need to be logged in to Kaggle in order to download a file.

Comment: any other place where i can get this dataset without a pwd ?

Comment: @kiriloff: As @mechanical_meat said, you need to login in kaggle or use 'API token' provided in your profile settings in Kaggle.com. Then you can use Kaggle command (`pip install kaggle`) to download the dataset using downloaded token (`kaggle datasets download -d quora/question-pairs-dataset`). If you're ok with this, I can post an answer how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

Clearly what you got is not ZIP file, `Content-Type` response header is useful for determining what you got, I did

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.kaggle.com/quora/question-pairs-dataset/download")
print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
```

output

```
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

So this is HTML page, as *my browser is loading a zip file* I suspect that access to this resource required being logged in otherwise you are redirect to page allowing logging in. To make `requests`-based downloading work you would need to find how checking is done by Kaggle and conform to it.

Answer (score 0):

First try to use `response.raw.decode_content = True`

Like so:

```py
import requests, zipfile, io

response = requests.get("https://www.kaggle.com/quora/question-pairs-dataset/download")
response.raw.decode_content = True
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
z.extractall(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: how do i either name the file with my preferred name, or find the name of the unzipped file ?

Comment: it is crashing the same way